# Is there any free clipboard manager like Ditto for Mac?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I'm looking for a clipboard manager for Mac OS, similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97507/is-there-anything-like-the-clipboard-manager-ditto-for-mac) but it seems that one is a bit outdated and doesn't accept new answers and also not specifically requesting a "free" alternative.